# What type of trigonometric integral is $\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \sin^{2}(x)\sin(n\pi x)\,dx$?

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry, trigonometric-integrals

None of the trigonometric integrals look like the integral I have written.

I need use some type identity trigonometric ?

$$ \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \sin^{2}(x)\sin(n\pi x)\,dx
$$

Comment: You could for example use $$\sin^2x=\frac12\left(1-\cos2x\right)$$ and then $$\cos\alpha\sin\beta=\frac12\left(\sin(\beta+\alpha)+\sin(\beta-\alpha)\right)$$

Comment: Or easier: the function $\;\sin^2x\sin npi x\;$ is odd...!

Comment: Oh yes, the function is odd. I was really tired and didn't see it. Of course it is 0. Thank you/ Muchas gracias.

Comment: That looks like an integrals ued to evaluate the Fourier coefficients of some function, perhaps $\;\sin^2x\;$ ... noticing that it is even will save lots of times doing those integrals, as it happens in this case we get as cosines series. If it is not for Fourier analysis forget what I wrote here right now.

Answer (score 1):

Let

$$f_n(x)=\sin^2(x)\sin(n\pi x).$$

Then notice that

\begin{align*}
f_n(-x) &= \sin^2(-x)\sin(n\pi (-x)) \\
&= (-\sin(x))^2-\sin(n\pi x) \\
&= -\sin^2(x)\sin(n\pi x) \\
&=-f_n(x).
\end{align*}

Thus $f_n$ is even, and since the integral is over a symmetric interval, we have that

$$\int_{-\pi}^\pi f_n(x)\,\mathrm{d}x=0.$$

Answer (score 1):

$\sin^2x$ being even, and $\sin(n\pi x)$ being odd, the given function is odd, and hence has an integral $0$ on a symmetric (around $0$) interval.